# I can't seem to pydoc raw_input in the terminal(Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10-desktop, pydoc

I am a newbie in programming and I am using Windows and Python2.7.

I tried to run `python -m pydoc raw_input` in the terminal, but it says:

```
'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) is the UNIX/Linux default "pager" command. Your python seems to think you are on a machine with the aforementioned command installed. No idea how to fix it, though.

Comment: Try `python -c "help(raw_input)"`; [edit] your question with the results.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work same reply was given

Comment: To be honest, that's what I expected to happen. It's *more-or-less* the same thing. Oh well, had to try.

Comment: Try just `more` on it's own to see if it's installed. If it's installed it should output something like `more: bad usage`. If not, it should output the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\srv> python -m pydoc raw_input
Help on built-in function raw_input in module __builtin__:

raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
    If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
    On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
    is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

`more.com` lives in `c:\windows\system32\more.com`, so make sure your path contains the `system32` directory..